# htaccess rewrite rules access site via IP address doesn't process rules non www to www etc

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rule made so far, but it isn't working as I hoped.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# (1) Redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# (2) Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# (3) Direct access through IP
# CHANGE 11.11.11.11 TO YOUR ACTUAL IP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.11\.11\.11$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What I want to achieve, is if I access my site via its IP address (eg: 11.11.11.11) then none of the following rules occur:

if I access it as:

http://example.com.au/(subfolders/etc)

it 301 redirects to:

https://www.example.com.au/(subfolders/etc)

if I access it as:

http://www.example.com.au/(subfolders/etc)

it 301 redirects to:

https://www.example.com.au/(subfolders/etc)

if I access it as:

https://example.com.au/(subfolders/etc)

it 301 redirects to:

https://www.example.com.au/(subfolders/etc)

Comment: So what's not working? Other than the last rule causing a redirect loop?

Comment: The redirect loop part.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do with the last rule (the IP one)

Comment: There are several things wrong with that 3rd set, including the condition and probably the order. As Jon noted, it's unclear that if you want to access the site via IP and it show the IP in the address bar or you expect it to redirect to the HOSTNAME as well? And then not process your other rules. Need to be a bit clearer on what you need.

Comment: Yes, if I access the site VIA ip address I want it to access via IP - so not to execute the other rules.

Comment: Would moving (3) to (0) be enough to make it work, or will it cause a redirect loop still? I can't test it easily as the site is live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last rule, that causes a redirect loop. Instead either add this rule to the top:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.11\.11\.11$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Or add this condition to your other two rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# (1) Redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^11\.11\.11\.11$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# (2) Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^11\.11\.11\.11$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trialing now with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ - thanks much, worked perfectly.